# Sklearn Pipeline with multiple estimators

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, transform, pipeline

Facing the error while chaining the estimators and trying to view. Iam new to Python and this was the first time i tried this pipeline function.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

estimator=[('dim_reduction',PCA()),('logres_model',LogisticRegression()),('linear_model',LinearRegression())]

pipeline_estimator=Pipeline(estimator)
```

Error message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-196-44549764413a> in <module>
----> 1 pipeline_estimator=Pipeline(estimator)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in __init__(self, steps, memory, verbose)
    112         self.memory = memory
    113         self.verbose = verbose
--> 114         self._validate_steps()
    115 
    116     def get_params(self, deep=True):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _validate_steps(self)
    157             if (not (hasattr(t, "fit") or hasattr(t, "fit_transform")) or not
    158                     hasattr(t, "transform")):
--> 159                 raise TypeError("All intermediate steps should be "
    160                                 "transformers and implement fit and transform "
    161                                 "or be the string 'passthrough' "

TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'LogisticRegression()' (type <class 'sklearn.linear_model._logistic.LogisticRegression'>) doesn't
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, all intermediate steps in a `Pileline` must be transformers (for feature transformations) and have `fit/transform` methods, however you've chained two models. You should just have one, and at the end of the pipeline.

It looks like you probably want to perform a grid search, comparing both estimators ,along their corresponding pipelines and hyperparameter tuning. For that use [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), with the defined `Pipeline` as estimator:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('dim_reduction', PCA()),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression()),
])
parameters = [
    {
        'clf': (LogisticRegression(),),
        'clf__C': (0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100)
    }, {
        'clf': (RandomForestClassifier(),),
        'clf__n_estimators': (10, 30),
    }
]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)

# some example dataset
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_tes, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

---

Also note that you're mixing a classifier and a regressor. The above shows how you could do this by combining two example classifiers. Though you might want to take some time in understanding which kind of problem you're facing, and which models would be appropriate for it.